# Exit when the result is ready and do not wait for the rest job?

Tags: awk, sleep, exit, head

I want to exit immediately when the result has been provided and do not wait for the rest of the jobs. I provided three examples by different approaches, i.e. awk, head and read. I want to exit after the '1' is shown in the following example without waiting for sleep. But none of the do not work. Is there any guy to help me?

```
(echo 1; sleep 10; seq 10) | head -n 1
(echo 1; sleep 10; seq 10) | awk -e 'NR==1{print $1;exit}'
(echo 1; sleep 10; seq 10) | ./test.sh
```

where the test.sh is the following:

```
while read -r -d $'\n' x
do
    echo "$x"
    exit
done
```

Comment: Warning: signs of jaundice ahead.  I suspect the problem is that modern shells think they need to wait for all the processes in the pipeline to exit before continuing.  At any rate, during the 10 seconds, the `awk` process is not visible in `ps`, so it has terminated.  I'm pretty sure that once upon a different millennium, shells did things differently; when the `awk` exited, the shell would have continued with the main shell — not caring about the status of its other progeny (the `(echo…sleep…seq)` sub-shell).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Bash waits for pipeline processes except when asynchronous. This seems like sensible behavior to me for the reasons I outline below, but coroutines, asynchronous pipelines, and named pipes might offer workable alternatives if a given shell doesn't support process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

### Refactor Using Bash Process Substitution

> I want to exit after the '1' is shown in the following example without waiting for sleep.

By default, [Bash shell pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) wait for each pipeline segment to complete before processing the next segment of the pipeline. This is usually the expected behavior, because otherwise your commands wouldn't be able to act on the completed output of from each pipeline element. For example, how could *sort* do its job in a pipeline if it doesn't have all the data available at once?

In this specific case, you can do what you want, but you have to refactor your code so that awk is reading from [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) rather than a pipe. For example:

```
$ time awk -e 'NR==1 {print $1; exit}' < <(echo 1; sleep 10; seq 10)
1

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s
```

From the timings, you can see that the process exits when awk does. This may not be *how* you want to do it, but it certainly does what you want to accomplish with a minimum of fuss. Your mileage with non-Bash shells may vary.

### Asynchronous Pipelines

Asynchronous pipelines are not really a generic solution, but using one works sufficiently to accomplish your goals for the given use case. The following returns immediately:

```
$ { echo 1 & sleep 10 & seq 10 & } | awk -e 'NR==1 {print $1; exit}'
1
```

because the commands in the [command list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists) are run asynchronously. When you run commands asynchronously in Bash:

> The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0 (true).

However, note that this only *appears* to do what you want. Your other commands (e.g. `sleep` and `seq`) are actually still running in the background. You can validate this with:

```
$ { echo 1 & sleep 10 & seq 10 & } | awk -e 'NR==1 {print $1; exit}'; pgrep sleep
1
14921
```

As you can see, this allows awk to process the output of `echo` without waiting for the entire list of commands to complete, but it doesn't really short-circuit the execution of the command list. Process substitution is *still* likely to be the right solution, but it's always good to know you have alternatives.